# how to disable gravity of a model in the world? (only disable one model)

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I want to disable the gravity of one model in gazebo world. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3338/how-to-disable-gravity-of-a-model-in-the-world?-(only-disable-one-model)/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/399/adrianpeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok, I got it. Just go to .sdf file and add
0
under  tag.

---

Originally posted by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/399/adrianpeng/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0